# Ignite kernel state is always showing stopped

Tags: ignite

I have a cluster of 3 nodes. native persistence is disabled. The cluster should be activated automatically as no persistence is enabled. But when I am connecting any cluster node with Mbean state inside Kernek-Ignition is always showing as **STOPPED**.

1. Do I need to start the cluster explicitly if native persistence is disabled?
2. As I can't see any error, How to make sure the cluster is not stopped after starting due to some
   issue in production?
3. I know there are events, is there any standard way to handle state change in production.
4. Attempt to change the state from MBEAN is not working for me. Any way to fix it.

Comment: Can you provide a runnable reproducer for that?

Comment: I think the state is showing in MBEAN is for the default instance name. Any way to change this default name?

Comment: `IgniteConfiguration.setInstanceName()`?

Comment: The instance name is already set. How come I make Mbean showing the state of instance rather than the state of the default instance.

Comment: Maybe you need to acquire a different mbean?